# I am trying to create a button that traces when it gets clicked in ActionScript 3, why am I getting error 1046?

Tags: actionscript-3, compiler-errors

I'm trying to make a game for a school assignment and I'm trying to make a button that, for now, will just trace that it has been clicked. However, anytime I try to run it it says "1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MouseEvent." Here is the code:

[Image of part of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Rk6I.png)
(apparently I can't embed an image so I hope this works...)
This is in the button's code, not the stage.

I've tried figuring it out and looking up how to solve this however can't find the answer. I'm not sure what the cause is or how to solve it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: There is no `fl.` to import, instead try as `import flash.events.MouseEvent;` or better still, just use `import flash.events.*;` , to cover all needed event types (the compiler will auto-add only the types that are used in your code). PS: Why not just paste the code text into your question (it's better and easier than some image upload process)?

Comment: Yes thank you this worked. It was so simple. Next time I have a question I will do that. Thanks again.